# How to add multiple link in single column

Tags: theming

I am new to drupal, and developing module to save car makes. I want to display that make in table format. Up to this i have completed. Now I have column of action where I want to display 2 links edit, delete. But I can display only one link with my current code. can anyone please help me, here is my code

```
 function manage_make()
 {
   $output=drupal_get_form('make_form');
   $query="SELECT * FROM {make_master}";
   $make_list=db_query($query);
   /*create table */
   $header=array('Make ID','Make Name','Status','Operatios');
   $rows=array();
   /*read data*/
   if($make_list->rowCount() > 0)
   {
       while($data=$make_list->fetchAssoc())
       {
           $rows[]=array(
            array('data'=>$data['make_id']),
            array('data'=>$data['make_name']),
            array('data'=>($data['make_status']==1) ? 'Active':'Block'),
            array('data'=>t('Edit')),
          );
       }
   }
return  theme('table',array('header'=>$header,'rows'=>$rows,"empty"=>t('Sorry, no makes available')));
}
```

Comment: The closest thing Drupal has to a helper function is `theme_item_list()` - probably overkill for this. Just use whatever PHP method you would usually use to concatenate two strings and assign the result to the final column